# How to properly name tpl file for webform-submission-navigation.tpl.php?

Tags: theming, webforms

I am trying to theme the webform-submission-navigation.tpl.php template to add a link for a specific node but am having no success.

If I edit the main webform-submission-navigation.tpl.php file I can achieve what I require but for all of the webform nodes. What I want is to ONLY have this link for 1 specific webform (node 139).

What I have tried to do is name the file as follows, put them in the corresponding themes template folder and the reset cache but have no success:

webform--submission--navigation--139.tpl.php
webform-submission-navigation--node--139.tpl.php

Am I naming my file incorrectly?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Copy webform-submission-navigation.tpl.php to your active theme templates directory
- Clear Drupal Cache
- Add a php condition in above tpl to render your link only for node 139

Code you need to use in above tpl...

```
<?php
 if ($node->nid == 139) {
    print l('You Link Title', 'link/path');
 }
?>
```